# How to pause time if action is processing for IAsyncResult

Tags: c#

How to pause if there is activity in the action?

Here is my code.

```
    private void RunWithTimeout(Action action, int timeoutMilliseconds)
    {
        Thread threadToKill = null;
        Action wrappedAction = () =>
        {
            threadToKill = Thread.CurrentThread;
            action();
        };

        IAsyncResult result = wrappedAction.BeginInvoke(null, null);

        if (result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeoutMilliseconds, true))
        {
            wrappedAction.EndInvoke(result);
        }
        else
        {
            threadToKill.Abort();
            wrappedAction = null;
            throw new TimeoutException();
    }

    private void DoSubscription()
    {
        // Subscribe the connection. 
        StompConnection connection = PrepareConnection();
        while (connection.getStompSocket() != null)
        {
            try
            {
                RunWithTimeout(() => StartProcessing(connection), 1200000);// 20 minutes
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (e is System.TimeoutException)
                {
                    _log.Debug(GetType().Name + " Timed out. Reconnecting...");
                }
                else
                {
                    SetSubscriptionError(e);
                }
                // Reconnection happens here
                run();
            }
        }
    }

    private void StartProcessing(StompConnection connection)
    {
        // "9999999999" is the timeout before it receive something from STOMP. There is an error in this method (after 5 seconds, it will not throw error, and the server that I subscribed kick me after 20 minutes, so I have to use another method to override this timeout to resubscribe to the server)
        Message = connection.receive(9999999999);
        if (Message.getBody() != null)
        {
            //result = true;
            string msgBody = Message.getBody();

            // Process the message body to extrace data that I need
            OnReceive(msgBody);
        }
        connection.ack(Message, Transaction);
    }
```

`DoSubscription()` is the method to use `RunWithTimeOut()`. However, let's say the timeout is 20 minutes, and there is message coming in at 19 minutes 58 seconds, and the `StartProcessing()` method is not finish executing and once reach 20 minutes, `RunWithTimeOut()` will throw a timeoutexception to end the thread. So it means my `StartProcessing()` is not finished its action.

So any idea to improve my methods to pause when there is action in the `StartProcessing()`?

- Actually it does something in the `StartProcessing()`, where it is at `Message = connection.receive(9999999999);` <------ Waiting server to post something to me. However, as you can read comment above the line, I have to use external method to do reconnection. So I prefer the thread-pause is after the `Message.getBody() != null`.

Comment: Hmmm...Nobody knows the solution?